# Materialize CSS select dropdown arrow displaced

Tags: css, django, materialize

Below is a screen shot of the materialize css as seen from:
https://materializecss.com/select.html

But for some reason, I get the little arrow of the drop down under the list rather than on the side.

I am using Django 3.

How do I fix this?

[image: Screen Shot of the materializecss DropDown]

And the following is the HTML of the rendered page:

```
<html><head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js">
      </script>




          <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    });
      </script>
</head>
<body class="vsc-initialized">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo right">SIW</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

    <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">


            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <div class="select-wrapper"><input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df80"><ul id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df80" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" style=""><li class="disabled selected" id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df800" tabindex="0"><span>Choose your option</span></li><li id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df801" tabindex="0"><span>Option 1</span></li><li id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df802" tabindex="0"><span>Option 2</span></li><li id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df803" tabindex="0"><span>Option 3</span></li></ul><svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg><select tabindex="-1">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select></div>
                <label>Materialize Select</label>
            </div>


        </form>
    </div>
    </div>



<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<div class="hiddendiv common"></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using multiple conflicting versions of `materialize` both `1.0.0` and `0.97.3`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Select only the `1.0.0` version on both the `.css` and `.js` files, for it to work.

Below is a snippet using the `HTML` code you provided.

```html
<html><head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      </script>




          <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    });
      </script>
</head>
<body class="vsc-initialized">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo right">SIW</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

    <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">


            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <div class="select-wrapper"><input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df80"><ul id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df80" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" style=""><li class="disabled selected" id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df800" tabindex="0"><span>Choose your option</span></li><li id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df801" tabindex="0"><span>Option 1</span></li><li id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df802" tabindex="0"><span>Option 2</span></li><li id="select-options-07dbac11-476d-4358-8e69-a8d561e0df803" tabindex="0"><span>Option 3</span></li></ul><svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg><select tabindex="-1">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select></div>
                <label>Materialize Select</label>
            </div>


        </form>
    </div>
    </div>



<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<div class="hiddendiv common"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: @OsandaGunasena Great! Don't forget to upvote if it was helpful! Glad I could help ;D

Comment: This is still not correct. There are two dropdown icons showing when the snippet is run.

Comment: @SeanDoherty That's not the OP issue, so it's not relevant. However I've copied exactly from the OP so its up to the poster to decide. If you want you can edit my answer, but the main issue has been solved already.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte pretty sure it's relevant. It's important to fix all possible errors in the code - the double caret is a problem. I'm not interested in stealing your points, but your answer still contains errors which you wouldn't really want in production (such as JS in the head, and before materialize.js is served)

Comment: @SeanDoherty That's a matter of opinion I'm afraid. Only the Original Poster should decide what is relevant or not. And trying to solve "everything" may lose focus on the main issue. I'm not saying for you not to post an answer, in fact I'm quite happy for that, but a "more complete" answer doesn't make another answer incorrect.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte I totally understand what you are saying, but if you know the framework then you'll know something is wrong there, and I wouldn't let that pass.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte actually, the error is with you. When you copied the provided code into the code snippet window, it incorrectly copied the dynamically generated output alongside it - I know this, because it happened with me too. Materialize hides the native select and creates a dropdown. This is why your example is displaying wrong, but I'm guessing because you don't know the framework, you just let it pass. If you put as much effort into your answer as you did your retorts, maybe you'd have spotted it ;)

Comment: @SeanDoherty I've spotted, but waited for the SO to decide if it was meaningful or not. Which he didn't think it was. For the sake of simplicity, keep it stupid simple. ;D

Comment: Thank you to both Bernardo Duarte and Sean Doherty, new to CSS and JS, so both your answers are much appreciated and valued!

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things wrong with your code, and the accepted answer:

1) You had JS in the head. JS should go at the end, before the closing body tag.

2) The answer had materialize.js at the end - after it is used in your function in the head. This was causing the double carets.

3) You are serving jQuery but never using it. If you do need it, it should be served first, followed by materialize.js, and then your own custom JS (where you run your inits).

```html
<html>
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">



</head>
<body class="vsc-initialized">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo right">SIW</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
            <div class="input-field col s5">
                <select>
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
                <label>Materialize Select</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    });
</script>



<div class="hiddendiv common"></div></body></html>
```